# Javascript: How to ensure sequential execution with multiple nested loops using setTimeout delays?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have been looking up many of the SO posts on setTimeout() and loop delays, but haven't been able to come up with a working solution. I'm doing an animated presentation of some data in the browser, where I need to redraw the same sequence multiple times, with events occurring in a specific order, including an inner loop with delays. Like so:

```
for (var pass = 1; pass <= passes; pass++) {

    // 1. Prep some data, update DOM (must happen *before* inner loop)

    // 2. Run inner loop with delays (multiple DOM updates...)
    (function loopWithDelay() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            // Iterate on data
            // Update DOM on each iteration
            if ( !condition() ) { 
                loopWithDelay(); 
            }
        }, 250);   // delay at each iteration
    })(); 

    // 3. Do wrap-up calcs, update DOM (must happen *after* above loop)

}   // If more passes remain, repeat..
```

So, I was able to delay the the iteration of the inner loop (part 2), however since it's non-blocking, part 3 executes right away, and so the parent loop doesn't work correctly. I somewhat understand the async/non-blocking nature of Javascript but can't wrap my head around how to do a multi-sequence like this cleanly (or actually get it to work at all!) Would love some advice for this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it like this (I call it callbacl loop):

```
function outerloop(pass, passes) {
    if (pass > passes) return;
    // 1. Prep some data, update DOM (must happen *before* inner loop)

    // 2. Run inner loop with delays (multiple DOM updates...)
    (function loopWithDelay() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            // Iterate on data
            // Update DOM on each iteration
            if (!condition()) {
                loopWithDelay();
            } else {
                outerloop(pass++, passes);
            }
        }, 250); // delay at each iteration
    })();

    // 3. Do wrap-up calcs, update DOM (must happen *after* above loop)

}
outerloop(1, passes);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'll want to use async methods, your design needs to change into [event-driven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) instead of structured.

Basically, you'll need to use `callback`s to handle the delays (or Promises if you want to be *cutting edge* :D )

I was thinking of somethine like this:

```
(function() {
  var after_loop = function() {
    // Move 3 here
    // 3. Do wrap-up calcs, update DOM (must happen *after* above loop)
  }

  var loopWithDelay = function() {
    // update whatever DOM you want
    updateDom();

    // Check if we need to stop the looping
    if (stop_condition) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      after_loop();
    }
  }

  var interval = setInterval(loopWithDelay, 250);
})();
```

`loopWithDelay` will be called every 250 ms, and when `stop_condition` will be true, it will stop running and run `after_loop();`

Comment: Thanks! I think I get it, will have a go at it. I still need to make sure that Part 1 of the tasks gets executed *before* I start the interval (would I simply place that code before this self-exec function block?), and how to repeat all of it multiple times (with the sequencing maintained..)

Comment: I accepted Mehran's answer, however, I was able to adapt your method as well: I named the parent anonymous function, added arg of `pass`, and auto-executed it as `(function() {...})(passes);` I decrement `pass` inside `afterLoop()` and call the parent again if passes remain. I also added a new `beforeLoop()` function, which runs the first time `loopWithDelay()` is invoked by the interval (using a flag to clear/set). Mehran's solution feels a touch cleaner to me but both work and I appreciate your explanation of event-driven programming!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe...?

```
var states = {
 beforeLoop: 0,
 innerLoop: 0,
 afterLoop: 0
};
var timeouts = {
 beforeLoop1: undefined,
 beforeLoop2: undefined,
 innerLoop1: undefined,
 innerLoop2: undefined,
 afterLoop1: undefined,
 afterLoop2: undefined
}
function setTimeoutType(fun,time,type){
 states[type]++;
 return setTimeout(fun,time);
}
function mainLoop(){
 if(beforeLoop1 == undefined)
  beforeLoop1 = setTimeoutType(beforeFun1,1000,'beforeLoop'); 
 if(beforeLoop2 == undefined)
  beforeLoop2 = setTimeoutType(beforeFun2,1000,'beforeLoop'); 
 if(states.beforeLoop == 0){
  if(innerLoop1 == undefined)
   innerLoop1 = setTimeoutType(innerFun1,1000,'innerLoop'); 
  if(innerLoop2 == undefined)
   innerLoop2 = setTimeoutType(innerFun2,1000,'innerLoop'); 
  if(states.innerLoop == 0){
   if(afterLoop1 == undefined)
    afterLoop1 = setTimeoutType(afterFun1,1000,'afterLoop'); 
   if(afterLoop2 == undefined)
    afterLoop2 = setTimeoutType(afterFun2,1000,'afterLoop'); 
   if(states.afterLoop == 0){
    // loops done
   }
   else setTimeout(mainLoop,1000);
  }
  else setTimeout(mainLoop,1000);
 }
 else setTimeout(mainLoop,1000);
}
function beforeFun1(){
 // code
 states.beforeLoop--;
}
function beforeFun2(){
 // code
 states.beforeLoop--;
}
function innerFun1(){
 // code
 states.innerLoop--;
}
function innerFun2(){
 // code
 states.innerLoop--;
}
function afterFun1(){
 // code
 states.afterLoop--;
}
function afterFun2(){
 // code
 states.afterLoop--;
}
function startThisHugeThing(){
 timeouts = {
  beforeLoop1: undefined,
  beforeLoop2: undefined,
  innerLoop1: undefined,
  innerLoop2: undefined,
  afterLoop1: undefined,
  afterLoop2: undefined
 }
 setTimeout(mainLoop,1000);
}
```